# argparse-assign list items to variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

I want to pass multiple arguments using cmd to the python script. below is the code I have used.

```
import argparse

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('-n', '--names-list', nargs='+', default=[])  
#item1 item2 item3 item4
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

a = args.names-list[0]
b= args.names-list[1]
c=args.names-list[2]
d=args.names-list[3]

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d)
```

when I execute the code I got an error message like below.

```
File "D:\script.py", line 7, in <module>
a = args.names-list[0]
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'names'
```

as I'm very new to this, can somebody help me to solve the problem?

Comment: See the dupe target: `a = args.names-list[0]` is actually `a = args.names - list[0]`. What you want is `a = args.names_list[0]`

Comment: I disagree that this is a dupe. OP has multiple errors, only one of which is resolved by the duplicate.

Comment: @Robᵩ While true, the dupe target also shows the proper usage of parse_args and the dupe does address the specific question asked/error encountered. The answer you wrote is still helpful to the OP I'm sure, but future readers will likely be better served via the dupe.

Comment: When debugging `argparse` it helps to `print(args)` (even before use `vars`).  That will show all the attributes, their correct names, and values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is incorrect. You do not need to invoke `vars()`.

```
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

Instead, try this:

```
args = ap.parse_args()
```

Additionally, the argument names are automatically translated from using `-` to using `_`. Try this: `a = args.names_list[0]`

Here is your program, with corrections:

```
import argparse

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('-n', '--names-list', nargs='+', default=[])
#item1 item2 item3 item4
args = ap.parse_args()

a = args.names_list[0]
b= args.names_list[1]
c=args.names_list[2]
d=args.names_list[3]

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d)
```

And here is the result:

```
$ python x.py -n one two three four
one
two
three
four
```

Comment: I got an error like this.     a = args.names-list[0]
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'names'

Comment: You should use `args.names_list`, not `args.names-list`.

Comment: it shows an error message of  `list index out of range`

Comment: If you don't supply 4 arguments it will say that: `args.names_list` is only as long as the number of items you've put in it.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning if you want to force them to supply exactly 4 arguments, you can use `nargs=4` rather than `nargs='+'`